# HowTo get a Map from a csv string

Tags: string, scala, csv, dictionary, split

I'm fairly new to Scala, but I'm doing my exercises now.
I have a string like

```
"A>Augsburg;B>Berlin"
```

. What I want at the end is a map

```
val mymap = Map("A"->"Augsburg", "B"->"Berlin")
```

What I did is:

```
val st = locations.split(";").map(dynamicListExtract _)
```

with the function

```
private def dynamicListExtract(input: String)  = {
    if (input contains ">") {
      val split = input split ">"
      Some(split(0), split(1)) // return key , value
    } else {
      None 
    } 
  }
```

Now I have an

```
Array[Option[(String, String)
```

How do I elegantly convert this into a Map[String, String]

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Just change your `map` call to `flatMap`:

```
scala> sPairs.split(";").flatMap(dynamicListExtract _)
res1: Array[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = Array((A,Augsburg), (B,Berlin))

scala> Map(sPairs.split(";").flatMap(dynamicListExtract _): _*)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map((A,Augsburg), (B,Berlin))
```

For comparison:

```
scala> Map("A" -> "Augsburg", "B" -> "Berlin")
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map((A,Augsburg), (B,Berlin))
```

Comment: Another trick to know is that `Map`'s `++` method takes a `TraversaleOnce` so you could use `st` like so: `Map[String, String]() ++ st.flatMap(n => n)`. Randal's way is better.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. My problem was not the flatMap instead of map (although this is also helpful), but not knowing the 
<pre><code>Map(Seq(A,B) : _*) </pre></code> constructor.

Answer (score 9):

In 2.8, you can do this:

```
val locations = "A>Augsburg;B>Berlin"
val result = locations.split(";").map(_ split ">") collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) } toMap
```

`collect` is like `map` but also filters values that aren't defined in the partial function.  `toMap` will create a `Map` from a `Traversable` as long as it's a `Traversable[(K, V)]`.

Comment: I think that was I was actually looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth seeing Randall's solution in for-comprehension form, which might be clearer, or at least give you a better idea of what flatMap is doing.

```
Map.empty ++ (for(possiblePair<-sPairs.split(";"); pair<-dynamicListExtract(possiblePair)) yield pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (not handling error cases):

```
val str = "A>Aus;B>Ber"
var map = Map[String,String]()

str.split(";").map(_.split(">")).foreach(a=>map += a(0) -> a(1))
```

but Ben Lings' is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
val str= "A>Augsburg;B>Berlin"

Map(str.split(";").map(_ split ">").map(s => (s(0),s(1))):_*)

--or--

str.split(";").map(_ split ">").foldLeft(Map[String,String]())((m,s) => m + (s(0) -> s(1)))
```